# query regarding getop() in K&R C

Tags: c

In the function below:

1. Why it is terminating the string initially by s`[1] = '\0';`?
2. after `i = 0`, why starting to take values from `s[1]` not from `s[0]`?

```
#define NUMBER '0'
#define MAXSIZE 100
char s[MAXSIZE];

/* getop: get next character or numeric operand */

int getop(char s[ ])
{
    int i, c;

    while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
    s[1] = '\0';
    if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
        return c; /* not a number */
    i = 0;
    if (isdigit(c)) /* collect integer part */
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    if (c == '.') /* collect fraction part */
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    s[i] = '\0';
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);
    return NUMBER;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing `NUMBER` is a constant that is used to denote a numeric token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The function appears to store its result in a pointer to a *string*, in C style zero terminated. The first `getch` line stores its result in `s[0]`, and if it's not a digit or the period, it immediately returns. Storing a zero as the 2nd character makes sure the returned string is properly ended -- it contains only one character.
2. After that initial step you already have one valid character, and it's stored in `s[0]`. So, all next `getch` calls need to store from 1 onwards, or it would overwrite the first character entered.

Comment: Function is not returning string. Its return type is `int`.

Comment: Right (it returns some result code). The data gets stored in a string array of some un-mentioned and un-tested size. One can only hope that buffer is large enough! (That could be in Chapter 2, though.)